# bootstrap datetime picker change

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap 3 datetime picker. How can I change colors for working days and weekdays also. Also I would like to change color for weekdays and months title.

I'm struggling to inspect css styles for bootstrap datetime picker since I cannot use firebug on this control (once I click on firebug icon the datetime picker goes invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Bootstrap 3 Date time picker from Eonasdan](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), you can do :

For the **week days** :

```css
 .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .day
 {
  color: red;
 }
```

For the **week end days** :

```css
 .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .weekend
 {
  color: gold;
 }
```

For the **month titles** :

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget thead .picker-switch
{
 color: blue;
}
```

For the **day titles** :

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget thead .dow
{
 color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you add css like in your current page

```
   .ui-datepicker-current-day
      {
           background: #83C948
      }
         /* today's background color */
    .ui-datepicker-today 
    {
      background: #83C948
    }
```